# VBA macro worked at one time - now giving 1004 error "application defined or object defined error"

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I had a macro that was working until recently.  The macro essentially goes through each .xlsx file in a folder and copies a range of data from each file into a separate "summary" workbook.  The code is below.  The debugger shows me the line highlighted with asterisks below where the application/object error is, but I can't seem to figure it out. Any help is appreciated as I'm new to VBA and coding.

```
Sub SummariseDataCCETR13Test()
Dim SummWb As Workbook
Dim SceWb As Workbook
'Get folder containing files
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
 .AllowMultiSelect = False
 .Show
 On Error Resume Next
 myFolderName = .SelectedItems(1)
 Err.Clear
 On Error GoTo 0
End With
If Right(myFolderName, 1) <> "\" Then myFolderName = myFolderName & "\"
'Settings
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
oldStatusBar = Application.DisplayStatusBar
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Set SummWb = ActiveWorkbook
'Get source files and append to output file
myFileNum = 1
mySceFileName = Dir(myFolderName & "*.*")
myUsedCols = SummWb.Sheets("TestData").UsedRange.Columns
Do While mySceFileName <> "" 'Stop once all files found
 Application.StatusBar = "Processing: " & mySceFileName
 Set SceWb = Workbooks.Open(myFolderName & mySceFileName) 'Open file found
 Dim emptyColumn As Long
 emptyColumn = SummWb.Sheets("TestData").Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight).Column
 If emptyColumn > 1 Then
        emptyColumn = emptyColumn + 1
    End If
 **SceWb.Sheets("Summary").Range("A14:b150").Copy SummWb.Sheets("TestData").Cells(1, emptyColumn)**
 SceWb.Close (False) 'Close Workbook
 myFileNum = myFileNum + 1
 mySceFileName = Dir
Loop
'Settings and save output file
Application.StatusBar = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = oldStatusBar
SummWb.Activate
' SummWb.Save 'Uncomment this line if you want to save at the end of the process.
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Did the Summary sheet get deleted or renamed?

Comment: `emptyColumn = SummWb.Sheets("TestData").Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight).Column` is safer as `emptyColumn = SummWb.Sheets("TestData").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column` - suspect that is the problem.  Check the value of `emptyColumn` when it errors.

Comment: @TimWilliams, that was it! Thanks! Took me a minute but I think I wrapped my head around your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```vb
Dim emptyColumn As Long
emptyColumn = SummWb.Sheets("TestData").Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight).Column
If emptyColumn > 1 Then
    emptyColumn = emptyColumn + 1
End If
```

you run the risk of the `End(xlToRight)` taking you all the way over to the last column. If you then add 1 to that you're off the sheet.

This is safer as long as there's no other content to the right of your top row:

```vb
emptyColumn = SummWb.Sheets("TestData").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```